# Как итерироваться по массиву updates User Long Poll API?

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, бот

Создаю бота вконтакте. Использую User Long Poll API для получения сообщений от пользователя. Проблема возникает, когда боту пишет несколько человек(он не успевает всем отвечать, поскольку в коде программы обрабатывает только одно сообщение в массиве updates, а должен вроде как итерироваться по всем. Когда приходит несколько сообщений сразу, в массиве updates появляется дополнительный массив. Но в нем не отображается сообщение пользователя, которое как раз и было **ПОТЕРЯНО**.
Приходит ответ по типу {"ts":1745339246,"updates":[[80,1,0],[12,///ID///,2] <-(ТУТ НЕТУ ТЕКСТА СООБЩЕНИЯ),[4,886,17,///ID///,1595087289,"ТЕКСТ СООБЩЕНИЯ",{"title":" ... "}]]<-(ТУТ ЕСТЬ ТЕКСТ СООБЩЕНИЕ)}. Как мне достать из первого массива потерянное сообщение, на которое не ответил бот? Извиняюсь за длинный текст.

Answer (score 0):

В структуре ответа VK первая цифра - это код события.

Когда пришло новое сообщение - код события = 4.

Код 11 - прочий служебный код, который вас не должен интересовать.

Я бы порекомендовал в вашей ситуации предварительно отфильтровать массив updates так, чтобы там остались только события с кодами, которые вас интересуют (4) и ваш алгоритм будет работать, как ожидается.

Так же рекомендую ознакомиться с документацией по API:
https://vk.com/dev/using_longpoll_2?f=3.%2B%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%2B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9